# Failed to launch the apk file in appium through android emulator

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, android-emulator, appium

I'm configured the android emulator successfully, and the device is displayed as expected. Also I was successfully startup the appium server, and written the following script through eclipse.

When I execute the code is return the following exception in appium as well as in eclipse o/p console:

Exception:

```
> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\bharanik\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\build-tools'
>     at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
>     at exports.getDirectories (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\helpers.js:100:18)
>     at [object Object].ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:97:25)
>     at [object Object].ADB.checkAdbPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:134:8)
>     at Function.ADB.createADB (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:73:7)
>     at [object Object].androidCommon.initAdb (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1083:9)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:610:21
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:249:17
>     at iterate (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:149:13)
>     at async.eachSeries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:165:9)
>     at _asyncMap (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:13)
>     at Object.mapSeries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:231:23)
>     at Object.async.series (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:608:19)
>     at [object Object].ChromeAndroid.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\chrome.js:85:9)
>     at [object Object].Appium.invoke (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:285:17)
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:124:14)
>     at [object Object].ChromeAndroid.configure (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\chrome.js:73:3)
>     at [object Object].Appium.configure (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:250:15)
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:118:10)
>     at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:129:5)
>     at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
> info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
> info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 872882ff-89aa-4adb-9774-6506a3bd9c80
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 27.062 ms - 204 
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"4.4","deviceName":"Android Emulator","platformName":"Android","browserName":"Chrome"}}
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
> info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>     at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:139:15)
>     at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>     at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"872882ff-89aa-4adb-9774-6506a3bd9c80"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 10.559 ms - 250 
> Killed Node Server.
> Node Server Process Ended
```

Without any fix I tried to execute the same script but this time It returned some different exception as below:

Exception

```
 error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
> info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>     at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:139:15)
>     at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>     at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"872882ff-89aa-4adb-9774-6506a3bd9c80"}
```

Can somebody help What is the issue, and root cause? how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both says the same thing

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
> info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
```

There is an existing session in  the server which is running that emulator of yours .. restart your server and make sure no existing session is running when you request your driver object

Comment: I already restart the server several times. But still no luck. I just noticed in appium server and eclipse console that why it's pointing to the below location which is not exist.    > Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\bharanik\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\build-tools.   The "build-tools " folder actually is not existed in the file system. I don't know that Why its pointing to this directory. Also I tried in Appium general settings and checked-in "pre-launched app" option throws same exception and session not started.

Comment: I think you need to set the path of the build tools and platform tools in android sdk. You have done that incorrectly then . Please check and correct that

Comment: Actually, I checked in my SDK root directory, and I didn't find any folder as "build-tools". Platform-tools I already set in environement properties

Comment: How is that possible - I can see mine C:\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools . Where did you install it from.

Comment: Please download the latest one. The one you are using says 2013.

Comment: Okay. Let me check this out.

Comment: I downloaded the package which exactly you're using. But While installing API17 itself it throws following exception. "package 'ARM EABI v7 a system image, android API17, revision 3' depends on missing SDK platform Android,API 17" When I accept the licence this was displayed below the screen. Also I already updated the code with apk physical location in code level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95690/discussion-between-shamik-and-skumar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that you have not defined path to you `.apk` file in the `capabilities`.
E.g.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/root/apps/my_app.apk")
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "android")
```

And second of all it seems that you have wrong value in `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable - that should be why you get the `build-tools` path error.